Is "Italian language" still alive?
30 days after the go-live, the figures are not reassuring.
I encourage everyone to express their point of view: is this site still alive, has it ever been?

It's too early to say anything intelligent about your stats. At 30 days, it is way too soon.
Does this site have a chance of succeeding?
You are currently serving about 60+ users/day. French SE was running about twice the traffic you are in this same time frame, but they bottomed out at 46 users/day before establishing a steady pattern of growth. This is completely normal. The French Stack Exchange is now  serving several thousand users/day and doubling their traffic every 3-6 months.
Please stop watching your stats. It is counter productive. Focus on posting high-quality content and providing a fantastic end-user experience. That's all you need to worry about.

Your blog post is rather intresting, but then I quote JonH's comment (Jul 27 2011): “if you don't want me to worry change the stats so they aren't bold, red and telling me to be worried”
(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/#comment-60242)

@They, +1, interesting comment!

To me, it is alive and growing. I'm keeping track of the number of questions and, more importantly at this time, of the number of users (growing).
I mean to discuss this in a panel here in a few months when a sufficient amount of temporal data will be available.

Sì, lo spettro della sospensione del servizio per inattività è prossimo a materializzarsi, ma ritengo non si possa non rilevare come gli unici 'L' siti in crescita siano EL&U ed ELL; gli altri, compresi Spanish and French — riferiti a lingue parlate da centinaia di milioni, se non miliardi, di persone — sono pressoché sull'orlo del precipizio per carenza di utenti e domande, come nel nostro caso.
Certo! 
E non é difficile comprenderne le ragioni.
Sia per quanto riguarda EL&U, ancorché loro se la cantinino e se la suonino circa l'essere una comunità per linguisti, che per ELL il successo, a mio parere, è dovuto ai non madrelingua che continuano a porre domande assolutamente basilari corrispondenti a, per esempio e nella nostra lingua, «Cos'è corretto dire 'sono morto' o 'ho morto'?» 
Chiaramente se nessuno di noi qui puó fare simili domande, come è possibile, se non in presenza di non nativi della lingua, che IL continui ad esistere? 
Purtroppo la risposta è di per sé evidente, ed è per questo che altrove avevo proposto, senza positivo riscontro, di estendere i contenuti di IL alla cultura e alla storia italiana in genere, nonché anche alla lingua latina.
Certo, qualcuno contrario a questa prospettiva  ha anche suggerito di proporre, all'uopo, una nuova proposta su Area51, ma purtroppo questo qualcuno, a mio parere, non si rende sufficientemente conto della demenzialità della fase cosiddetta di 'commitment', che non consentirebbe a una siffatta proposta di essere mai on-line. 
Allora, conclusivamente, cosa fare? Niente purtroppo, se non  parafrasare una celebre frase di George Clooney, 'No non-native speakers, No IL!' 
That's all.

billions of speakers for French and Spanish is false. Well, but do we know what has been the rate of growth of users for those other sites you mention?

Trattare qui anche il latino mi pare una sciocchezza; piuttosto, riconsidererei la posizione rispetto ai dialetti.

This is so full of misinformation and incorrect stats, I don't even know where to begin. Every language site is experiencing excellent growth, and have never had more users than they do today.
